# How many electrons can an orbital of type f hold?

Tags: electrons, orbitals

I was taking a chemistry test and I encountered the following question:

> How many electrons can an orbital of type f hold?
>
> A. 6
>   B. 10
>   C. 2
>   D. 14
>   E. 1

Since there can be [-ℓ, ℓ] orientations and since the orbital type f has ℓ = 3, we should have 7 possible orientations with 2 spins, so ${7 \times 2 = 14}$, so I thought the correct answer was D (14).

However, I got it wrong and the correct answer is marked as C (2). Is it an error in the test, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 12):

You're correct that there are seven possible spatial orientations for an f-type orbital, and hence seven possible orbitals in one f-type sub-shell. However, the question specifically asks for the maximum number of electrons in one such orbital, and *any* single atomic orbital, regardless of the sub-shell type specified by $l$, can only hold two electrons. This is by virtue of the Pauli exclusion principle. Fourteen would be the maximum number of electrons across an entire f-type sub-shell, but the question only asks about one orbital.

Answer (score -1):

The question specifically ask that no.of electron an orbital of f subshell can hold.... As we know that f subshell contain 7 orbital and each orbital can hold maximum 2 electons so correct answer would be 2..we can simply understand this by taking the real life example imagine that there is house named f which consists of 7 rooms so similarly in this case house is a subshell and each room is an orbital... Thank you,

Comment: What new info this answer brings to be posted in the first place ?